# Using foreach with mysql results array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I want to search for `name` in text but I have this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
    $users = $db->query_read(" SELECT username FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . " user "); 
    $nameuser=array();
    while ($results = $db->fetch_array($users, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
        $nameuser[] = $results['username'];
    }
    foreach ($nameuser as $name)
    {
        if(strstr($post['message'], $name))
        {
            // create new PM
            $pmdm =& datamanager_init('PM', $vbulletin, ERRTYPE_ARRAY);
            $pmdm->set_info('is_automated', true);
            $pmdm->set('fromuserid', 1);
            $pmdm->set('fromusername', admin);
            $pmdm->set('title', 'some title');
            $pmdm->set('message', 'some text');
            $botpermissions['adminpermissions'] = 2;
            $pmdm->set_recipients($name, $botpermissions);
            $pmdm->set('dateline', TIMENOW); 
            $pmdm->save(); 
        }
    }
```

Edit :
use `stripos` Instead of `strstr`

Comment: The argument to `foreach` has to be an array. `$names` is a string that you just created with `implode`. Use `$nameuser`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks brother , you are right .. now no error , but the code don't do any result .. can you know why ?

Comment: try `echo(count($nameuser));` right before `foreach` line to see if any was found

Comment: @KimAlexander thanks brother i found th sloution with use `stripos` Instead of `strstr`

Comment: good luck with your project!

Comment: @KimAlexander Thank you brother for your cooperation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you:

```
$names = implode(',', $nameuser);
foreach ($names as $name)
```

just :

```
foreach ($nameuser as $name)
```

Comment: yeah... thanks brother , you are right .. now no error , but the code don't do any result .. can you know why ?

Comment: Not this one the code which is not showing any error i mean the current code which you are saying providing no output. .

Comment: @omardealo  mustn't it be: `\`" . TABLE_PREFIX . " user\` ")`  with ticks? is your table name include space?? or you should use `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "user")` if there is no space in table name

Comment: @KimAlexander , my table name don't include space , i can use query like `(" SELECT username FROM  user ")` There is no difference or a problem in both cases

Comment: there is a difference, in your current code you use space character after `TABLE_PREFIX` before user. so if TABLE_PREFIX = 'wp' real query will be `SELECT username FROM wp user ` which is not correct

Comment: @KimAlexander yeah i know that but the table name in datapase is only `user` if the table name wrong or there anything about table name will must show to me error , but no error , thanks